# Put join on Main thread unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote following Code :

```
public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable
{
private Thread t ;
private String threadName;

 ThreadDemo(String threadName)
 {

     this.t = new Thread(this,threadName);
     t.start();
 }

public void run()
{
    System.out.println("New thread has been started!!!" + t.getName());

}
public  static void main(String args[])
{
new ThreadDemo("Thread-1");

Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
try {
    t.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

new ThreadDemo("Thread-2");

}


 }
```

So i have putted the join method on main thread .  When i run it ,its execution never end.
Why it is so ? Why main thread doesn't end ? why it's running for infinite time.

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Comment: I got this in a book :
in a multithreaded program, the main thread must be the last
thread to finish running. If the main thread finishes before a child thread has completed,then the Java run-time system may "hang."

can anybody explain me why it so ??

Answer (score 6):

The `join()` method waits for the thread that you call it on to finish. In your code, you are calling `join()` on the current thread - that is the same thread as you are calling it from. The main thread is now going to wait for itself to finish. That never happens, because it's waiting on itself...

You should not join the main thread, but the thread that you started instead.

```
ThreadDemo demo = new ThreadDemo("Thread-1");

try {
    demo.t.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another perspective to this code....

This code will hang even if you do not initialize the ThreadDemo objects
within the main program.

In short all this code can be reduced to saying the following statement,
Thread.currentThread().join() will never return.